# Как перенести файлы из vs code в visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Я писал в vs code и узнал, что на C++ лучше писать в visual studio. Написал я много и хотел бы перенести все свои файлы в visual studio.

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы как-то исследовали этот момент, а не просто послушали совет.

Answer (score 1):

Создать новый проект, добавить в него старые файлы и отлаживать то, на что влияют различия в диалектах.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно установить visual studio и открыть проект выбрав нужную директорию в данной IDE.